# "fs: missing callback Error: EACCES" when running deployd application

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, deployd

I just downloaded deployd v0.6.10 through sudo npm install -g.
However, the app won'r run with the following error message;

starting deployd v0.6.10...
fs: missing callback Error: EACCES, open '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/deployd/.latestversion'

Help!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You installed deployd as root, so you'll either need to change access permissions on the executable (`sudo chown $YOUR_USER_NAME /usr/bin/dpd`) or run it as root.

Details at [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/deployd/deployd/issues/194)